# Can the EOS-M cameras use a wired remote and\or programmed wifi remote?

Tags: canon, remote, mirrorless, wifi

I'm looking for the lightest Mirrorless around (for a [skydiving helmet](https://petapixel.com/2015/12/03/photographer-shoots-skydivers-with-a-dslr-strapped-to-his-head/)). It must have a wired remote since it is inaccessible in freefall. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Canon_EOS_digital_cameras), the original 2012 EOS M model is the lightest of all Canons, with which I can then use my existing EF lenses. However, it seems like it only uses a wifi remote.

My questions:

1. Can any EOS-M camera use a wired remote? I'll use a [blow switch](http://www.chutingstar.com/blow-switch-still-camera-trigger) eventually.
2. Can any EOS-M camera use a programmed wireless remote? as in to program it to take a single photo every second or a burst in timed intervals.
3. Can any other mirrorless on the market have a wired remote while weighing under 300g?

for reference:
[image]

Comment: You know Canon has an email. You can send like emails with questions to them.

Comment: 1. Their answer was no. I'll have to rely on aftermarket solutions and maybe even Magic Lantern 2. My third question did not involve Canons

Comment: Absolute curiosity here: why the 300g limit?

Comment: Why is WiFi not usable? You can establish a direct connection between any Android/iOS phone and the WiFi enabled EOS M models. This could be done before exiting the plane. You wouldn't need physical access to the camera at that point.

Comment: No 300g limit. I just used it as a reference figure because the older EOS M camera were light like this so i was asking if another comparable camera exists.

Comment: @MichaelClark yes this is possible and probably the way to go for me as of now. Most photographers in the field use blow switches though. Wifi is fine as long as it is programmable (for still shots, not only video)

Comment: I just researched and found out the one fact that changes the game for me - EF-M vs. EF-S: Every equal focal length EF-M lens will be much shorter and lighter than that of its EF\EF-S counterpart. I didn't know it before - this is a big advantage for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the EOS M, you can try the **Audio Remote Shot Option** via your smartphone. ( Smartphone must have a standard headphone Jack).

You will need to install the **Tragic Lantern Firmware** on your Camera.

From the Tragic Lantern Camera Menu, turn on the **Audio Remote Shot option**.

Download and install the **Triggertrap App** on your Smartphone.

You will also need to **purchase the Triggertrap mobile dongle** for Canon (about $10)

And an **Audio to Audio Cable** where one end goes into the Dongle and the other end into the Smartphone.

From the Triggertrap App, you should now be able to trigger the shutter and also use it for timelapse.

Someone introduced me to this a few years ago and although a little fiddly at first, it worked just fine.

And if this option is still available, then I can't see why it wont still work.

Good Luck

[image]

Comment: This is getting closer to what I want. It won't be triggered by a loud noise right? Also can it be a button instead of a smart phone? If it's the headphones jack it is probably simple enough to have a clicker type switch attached on wire to the the triggertrap dongle

Comment: Also what's the difference between Magic and Tragic?

Comment: from what I recall, there was no loud noise. a simple red button on the smartphone screen that you touch and the shutter clicks with no additional noise. Regarding a clicker type button, I am not sure that this will work as this is an App based solution which activates the electronics in the dongle. Which in turn must produce a noise signal that goes through the mic input and triggers the shutter.

Comment: I think that solution could be hacked in to a biteswitch. The phone probably triggers a pulse from the audio jack and all you need to do is find out what the voltage is. Then use the biteswitch together with a battery of the same voltage will probably trigger the camera

Comment: It may be more complex than simple voltage. It may be pulsed signalling using the audio jack.

Comment: @PIXP - A fellow poster "salmonlawer" suggested this about ML - There are tons of modules that are within the program. I myself have it on my 1200D, and it has an intervalometer option built-in. If I was going skydiving, I could simply set up the intervalometer, and jump out without hesitation - Sounds like a solution

Comment: @AbdulQuraishi indeed and it seems like the way I might eventually go. Just that most people in the field use blow\bite switches for still shots. Continuous blow or bite for burst mode.